# Is $\min_{n \in \mathbb{N}} (\exp(nx)+2\exp(ny))^{1/(n+1)}$ a continuous function?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, continuity, convex-analysis

Let $D = \{(x,y)\mid x>y>0\}$ and
$$F_{n}(x,y) = (\exp(nx)+2\exp(ny))^{\frac{1}{n+1}}$$
where $(x,y) \in D$.

Since $x > y$,
$\partial F(x,y,n)/\partial n$ has the same sign as
$$h(t) = xt +2y - (t+2)\ln(t+2) - t \ln t$$
where $t = \exp((x-y)n)$
which means that there exists $\min_{n \in \mathbb{N}} F_{n}(x,y)$

Assume that
$$f(x,y) = \min_{n \in \mathbb{N}} F_{n}(x,y)$$
I want to know

1. Is $f(\cdot, \cdot)$ a continuous function?
2. How to prove that the set $S_{c} = \{ f(x,y) > c \mid (x,y) \in D, c > 0)$ is strictly convex.

Some simple properties：

- $f(x_{1},y) > f(x_{2},y)$ if $x_{1} > x_{2}$.
- $f(x,y_{1}) > f(x,y_{2})$ if $y_{1} > y_{2}$.

As for the second question, accroding my program, it is wrong. Actually, if we define $g(x,y) = \max_{n \in \mathbb{N}} F_{n}(x,y)$, then $g(\cdot)$ is concave.

Comment: It would be interesting another question just before your two questions: How do you know that the minimum is actually achieved?

Comment: @Crostul I think it does have minimum, and I have added the reason in my question

Comment: Can't you claim it's continuous based on the fact that the exponential function is continuous?

Comment: @VictorS. In general, I am not sure that $f(a,b) \text{ is continuous} \Rightarrow \min_{b \in \mathbb{N}}f(a,b) \text{ is continuous}$ is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function is well defined and continuous.

First: for all $x>y>0$ we have
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} F_{n}(x,y) = e^x$$
This can be easily proved using the fact that $\exp(nx) >>2\exp(ny)$: the term $2\exp(ny)$ is negligible, hence the limit is simply $\lim_n (e^{\frac{nx}{n+1}})$.

Now, let's solve the following inequality in the unknown $n$:
$$F_{n}(x,y) < e^x$$
this is equivalent to
$$e^{nx}+2e^{ny}<e^{(n+1)x}$$
dividing by $e^{nx}$ we get
$$1+2e^{n(y-x)}<e^x$$
After simple arithmetic we can solve
$$n > \frac{1}{x-y} \log \left( \frac{2}{e^x-1} \right)$$
Note that $e^x-1>0$ since $x>0$, so the $\log$ is always well defined.

Let $N$ be the minimum natural number such that the inequality is satisfied.

For all $n > N$ we have that
$F_{n}(x,y) < e^x$ still holds.

Fix $U$ a small neighbourhood of $(x,y)$.
Since the function $$g(x,y)=\frac{1}{x-y} \log \left( \frac{2}{e^x-1} \right)$$
is continuous on the domain $D= \{ (x,y) \mid x>y>0\}$, it is also continuous on $U$.

In particular, using the fact that the closure of $U$ is compact, there exists $N_U \ge N$ such that for all $n > N_U$
the inequality $$F_{n}(x',y') < e^x$$ holds for all  $(x',y') \in U$.

For all $(x',y') \in U$ consider $M$ big enough such that
$$F_{N_U}(x',y') < F_{m}(x',y') < e^{x'}$$
is true for all $m >M$.
Again we can think that $M$ does not depend on $x', y'$, but only on $U$ using compactness argument.

Then in $U$ we have
$$\min_{n \in \Bbb N} F_{n}(x,y) = \min_{N_U \le n \le M} F_{n}(x,y)$$
which is a minimum of finitely many continuous functions.

This means that in the whole $U$ the function is well defined and continuous.

By arbitrarity of $(x,y)$ we have that $f(x,y)$ is continuous at every point, thus it is continuous.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any idea about the second question? I want to prove that $\lambda f(x_1,y_1)+(1−\lambda)f(x_2,y_2)>f(\lambda x_1+(1−\lambda)x_2,\lambda y_1+(1−\lambda)y_2)$. And accroding to my programing, I think it is true. But I have no idea how to prove that.

Comment: No ideas, sorry.